# Facebook SDK Info in XCode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, facebook

I outsourced some app development work that also featured the installation of the Facebook SDK. The user pushes a button and their scores are posted on their Facebook page. I have access to the Facebook Developer admin tool, but I don't think they used the right App ID or App Secret. Does anyone know where I would be able to find these in the XCode file to confirm?

Comment: Well that will completely depend on where the developer placed them. So no we can probably nopt tell you.

Comment: Is there a common or recommended place? If not, is there an easy way to search all files in the project for the specific IDs? Thank you.

Comment: No, some  place it in the `info.plist`, in code directly or even in a `constants.h` and many many more possibilities. In Xcode you can pres cmd+shit+f to do a global search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In source code search   [[Facebook alloc] then find what key string is used for initWithAppId api.

```
 facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"254214584659950" andDelegate:self];
```